# Best way to create a categorical column of month names with incomplete months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `'Date'` column.  I want to turn it into a categorical column that includes all months `Jan` to `Dec`.  However, my column many not have all months represented.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=pd.date_range('2011-03-31', periods=4, freq='Q')))

df

        Date
0 2011-03-31
1 2011-06-30
2 2011-09-30
3 2011-12-31
```

---

I've tried

```
df.Date.dt.strftime('%b').astype('category')

0    Mar
1    Jun
2    Sep
3    Dec
Name: Date, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Dec, Jun, Mar, Sep]
```

You can see that only the four months in my column are represented as categories.  How do I get to

```
0    Mar
1    Jun
2    Sep
3    Dec
Name: Date, dtype: category
Categories (12, object): [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ..., Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need parameter `categories`:

```
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
print (df.Date.dt.strftime('%b').astype('category', categories=cats))

0    Mar
1    Jun
2    Sep
3    Dec
Name: Date, dtype: category
Categories (12, object): [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ..., Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pd.Categorical` and set the  categories manually with the `categories` parameter:

```
cat = pd.date_range('2011-01-1', periods=12, freq='M').strftime('%b')
out = pd.Categorical(df.Date.dt.strftime('%b'), categories=cat)
out
```

---

```
[Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec]
Categories (12, object): [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ..., Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the categories manually.

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 
          'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 
          'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df['Months'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%b').astype('category')
df['Months'] = df['Months'].cat.set_categories(months)
```